# HTTPS - spring web security - how to make server secure

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, https

I am creating spring rest service. I wanna secure it with https.

I know that using following solution:

```
 http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/secure/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest.hasRole("USER")
            .and()
        .requiresChannel()
            .anyRequest().requiresSecure();
```

I can force using https. But I do not know what else I have to do. Should I configure something else in spring security or it is enough? I am using tomcat. Should I install certificate? If yes, is existing possibility to install "test certificate"? How it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to add a comment, so you'll probably need to provide more information to get the answer you really want.

First off, to enable HTTPS, you *will* need an SSL certificate. If you're just testing/developing, you can generate your own self-signed certificate and ignore certificate warnings from your browser. If however this is a public-facing server, you'll need a valid SSL certificate from a certificate authority like GoDaddy or similar. Generating an SSL cert is probably outside the scope of this question, and there are a lot of guides out there for this (I would post links, but don't have enough rep).

The config you have shown is a valid way to force your application server to only communicate over HTTPS, however, it is not sufficient to actually enable HTTPS for your Tomcat server.

Depending on your setup, you have a few different options for enabling HTTPS.

1. If you're using Spring Boot with an embedded Tomcat server, then you can enable SSL by setting the server.ssl.* properties of your application.properties file, for example:

   ```
   server.port=8443
   server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
   server.ssl.key-store-password=secret
   server.ssl.key-password=another-secret
   ```

   Where keystore.jks is the path to your Java keystore that holds your SSL certificate. See [Spring Boot Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-configure-ssl) for more info.
2. If you're using a standalone Tomcat server, you'll need to modify Tomcat's server.xml in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml and add an SSL connector. For example:

   ```
   <!-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
   <Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
   ```

   This example is for Tomcat 7, but the process is similar for other Tomcat versions. See [Tomcat SSL](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) for more information.
3. If you are using a proxy/load balancer (like NGINX) you can add an SSL termination there. The proxy/load balancer then intercepts all HTTPS traffic and communicates over non-HTTPS connections to your application servers. This has the added bonus of not having to interfere with your application server to perform SSL-related maintenance like changing your certificate or config.

Comment: I am using spring and standalone Tomcat 8. Probably I understand a lot. But I have one more question. Is https encrypting data only on time of sending? Or I must decrypt it when I get the request in spring framework? 
For instance, can I normally get base64 authentication data from the header? Or must I decrypt it or do something other with that? ;) I hope you know what I mean. ;)

Comment: You shouldn't have to decrypt the request. The data you get from Spring/Tomcat should look like normal, non-encrypted data. The HTTPS encryption happens at the Tomcat/Servlet level and is handled for you transparently.

However, any fields/headers that you add to the request that are encrypted/encoded (like a Base64 encoded header) will need to be manually decoded by your application. Spring Security does have some built-in mechanisms for handling typical Authentication schemes (like basic authentication), so you may want to investigate those options.